# Specifying FFMPEG in the requirements section of 'buildozer.spec' causing [libavformat/network.o] Error 1

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, kivy, buildozer

My question relates to how to mitigate an ffmpeg requirement listed in a buildozer.spec that is causing compile errors using buildozer.

**GOAL:**

Using buildozer to ensure FFMPEG can be embedded within a small Kivy app so i can utilise youtube_dl functionality on my android phone.

**THE ISSUE:**
Specifying FFMPEG in the requirements section of 'buildozer.spec' causes the following error message:
*common.mak:60: recipe for target 'libavformat/network.o' failed

make: [libavformat/network.o] Error 1

make: Waiting for unfinished jobs...*

**What have I done to resolve myself:**
1. Ensured LOG LEVEL 2 is specified.

2. Upgraded cython from Version 21 to 27. Then downgraded to 25, then 21 then 20 to see if this resolved anything. It didn't.
3. In BUILDOZER.SPEC, switched between Android NDK crystax-ndk-10.3.2 and android-ndk-r16b. (Note have reverted back to Crystax 10.3.2) in my NDK PATH.
4. In BUILDOZER.SPEC, changed android.api from 19 to 15 (just to see if this has any positive effects).
5. executed: rm -Rf .buildozer between each compiling attempt.
6. **Part extract** of Buildozer.log:

   In file included from libavformat/dump.c:37:0:
   libavformat/avformat.h:893:21: note: declared here
        AVCodecContext *codec;
                    ^

   CC  libavformat/format.o

   CC  libavformat/golomb_tab.o

   CC  libavformat/h264dec.o

   CC  libavformat/hevc.o

   CC  libavformat/http.o

   CC  libavformat/httpauth.o

   CC  libavformat/id3v1.o

   CC  libavformat/id3v2.o

   CC  libavformat/img2.o

   CC  libavformat/isom.o

   CC  libavformat/log2_tab.o

   CC  libavformat/m4vdec.o

   CC  libavformat/metadata.o
   CC  libavformat/mov_chan.o

   CC  libavformat/mov.o

   CC  libavformat/movenc.o

   CC  libavformat/movenccenc.o

   CC  libavformat/movenchint.o

   CC  libavformat/mpegvideodec.o

   CC  libavformat/mux.o

   CC  libavformat/network.o

   In file included from libavformat/network.h:29:0,

                    from libavformat/network.c:22:

   libavformat/os_support.h:67:32: error: expected declaration specifiers or    '...'     before '(' token

    #  define lseek(f,p,w) lseek64((f), (p), (w))

                               ^
   libavformat/os_support.h:67:37: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...'     before '(' token

    #  define lseek(f,p,w) lseek64((f), (p), (w))

                                    ^
   libavformat/os_support.h:67:42: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...'     before '(' token

    #  define lseek(f,p,w) lseek64((f), (p), (w))

                                         ^
   common.mak:60: recipe for target 'libavformat/network.o' failed

   make:*  [libavformat/network.o] Error 1
   make: * Waiting for unfinished jobs....
7. **Part extract** of Buildozer.spec

   ## (str) Title of your application

   title = myapplication

   ## (str) Package name

   package.name = myapp

   ## (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)

   package.domain = org.test

   ## (str) Source code where the main.py live

   source.dir = .

   ## (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)

   source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

   ## (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching

   ## source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

   ## (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)

   ## source.exclude_exts = spec

   ## (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)

   ## source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

   ## (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching

   ## source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

   ## (str) Application versioning (method 1)

   version = 0.1

   ## (str) Application versioning (method 2)

   ## version.regex = **version** = '"['"]

   ## version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

   ## (list) Application requirements

   ## comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy

   requirements = ffmpeg,python2,hostpython2,kivy,youtube-dl

   ## (str) Custom source folders for requirements

   ## Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes

   ## requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

   ## (list) Garden requirements

   ## garden_requirements =

   ## (str) Presplash of the application

   ## presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

   ## (str) Icon of the application

   ## icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

   ## (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)

   orientation = portrait

   ## (list) List of service to declare

   ## services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

   ## OSX Specific

   ## author = © Copyright Info

   ## change the major version of python used by the app

   osx.python_version = 3

   ## Kivy version to use

   osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

   ## Android specific

   ## (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not

   fullscreen = 0

   ## (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)

   ## Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:

   ## red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,

   ## darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,

   ## olive, purple, silver, teal.

   ## android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

   ## (list) Permissions

   ## android.permissions = INTERNET

   ## (int) Android API to use

   ## android.api = 19

   ## (int) Minimum API required

   ## android.minapi = 9

   ## (int) Android SDK version to use

   ## android.sdk = 20

   ## (str) Android NDK version to use

   android.ndk = 10.3.2

   ## (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)

   ## android.private_storage = True

   ## (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)

   android.ndk_path = /home/gjones/Downloads/crystax-ndk-10.3.2

   ## (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)

   ## android.sdk_path =

   ## (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)

   ## android.ant_path =
8. Lastly, **when I remove ffmpeg from requirements** in buildozer.spec, **the .APK compiles successfully** and i can deploy it on to my phone with the KIVY GUI. Obviously, ffmpeg functionality is not present.

**Current Environment Specs:**

1. Running Linux Mint 17.2 as a Virtual Box VM
2. Buildozer Version: 0.35dev
3. Cython Version: 0.25

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Lastly, if there is no obvious solution via buildozer, do i need to compile ffmpeg for Android separately and somehow include this somewhere in the buildozer spec file to prevent this error message?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having this very same problem today. just adding ffmpeg to be able do display videos in my app on android. Fresh install a per kivy site. Everything from scratch. Still, fails compilation on this very same library.

Answer (score 0):

buildozer's ffmpeg recipe is broken on master. you have to set "p4a.branch = develop" on buildozer.spec to make ffpyplayer and ffmpeg work.

Comment: give some more information with code / commands syntax to understand better

Answer (score 0):

According to the large font of the variable source.include_patterns
it might be that the .spec file still shows # at the beginning of the line, so that could be one problem.

Try using placement as follows:

```
source.include_patterns = assets/images/*.png
```

to include all the files in the folder.